# Mysql Workbench import CSV 0 record imported

Tags: csv, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySql workbench to import CSV files all the time. And it's always working perfectly besides the only I issue Im having now is, there's a CSV file would not get imported. No error occured during the import process. But when import finished, it shows 0 record imported. I've checked the table columns so I'm sure the data type match the CSV file. What did I miss?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK. It was because I datatime format didn't match that in CSV file. It weird because I noticed it at first place, then I unmarked the date column to imported, it seems even you unmark the column, the mysql workbench still take that column into consideration.

Comment: Add its most basic, an system that exports should be able to import the same file... this is not the case.  2020 6.3.8 still an issue